# Recyclerview onclick item to database

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I want add a STRiNG t to database but OnClick View I can't pass the instructions  for add it in database I get error on that line

GestioneDB db = new GestioneDB(this);

error is "GestioneDB cannot e applied"

I have used a recyclerview for show a ten and I need to pass onclick item to database by

```
t = lista_show.get (getAdapterPosition ());

class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
    ArrayList<String> lista_show;


    public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> lista_shows) {
        lista_show = lista_shows;
    }


    @Override
    public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder (view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mdevice.setText (lista_show.get (position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista_show.size ();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView mdevice;


        public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener (this);
            mdevice = itemView.findViewById (R.id.device);



        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String t;
            t = lista_show.get (getAdapterPosition ());

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> lista_shows, Context context) { lista_show = lista_shows; }

Comment: I got and error on main activity on lista_show.

Comment: Ok I need to pass on MainActivity in New MainAdpater(lista_show, MainActivity. This)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this way to get adapter position in your onBindViewHolder:-

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              String t = String.valueOf(position);
              // now you can use t where you want
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In class `ViewHolder` add method `bingItem(String item)`, when that method is called update `TextView mdevice` inside that method and store `String item` in `ViewHolder`, add there one field `String currentItem` and store it there.

Now in your `onClick` write `t = currentItem;` and you have clicked item.

If you want to add it to db, you should pass listener from activity to the adapter, and then to holder and then call that listener, as it is passed from activity it can have context (or db reference) so you have everything you need to save it in db.

Comment: My problem is start onclick listener to MainActivity for recyclerview item.